# Uniqueness constraint ruby on rails field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unique

I am new to ROR and been trying to fumble my way through the tutorial by mike hartl( excellent read for starters i might add ). There is however something i am struggling with, my user model looks like below.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates :name , :presence => true, :length => {:maximum => 50 }
    validates :email, :presence   => true,
                    :format     => { :with => email_regex },
                    :uniqueness => true
end
```

I then open the ruby console using rails -c and create a new user

```
usr = User.new(:name=>"abcd",:email=>"svsvenu@gmail.com")
```

I then save it by using

```
usr.save
```

This created a new record in my database. So far so good.but if i type 
usr.save 
again, nothing happens, i look at the database ( sqlite ) and not even the last update date changed.

Another interesting thing i noticed is when i use

```
User.create(:name=>"abcd",:email=>"svsvenu@gmail.com"),
```

multiple times, there is a record created every time i run it in the console.

Can some one please explain why my save does not work and also why my uniqueness constraint is being ignored?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord is smart enough to understand that when you type `usr.save` twice in a row, the 2nd one is redundant.

```
usr = User.new
usr.save # usr is saved (if it was valid)
usr.save # usr is already saved and unchanged!  do nothing.
usr.name = "bananas"
usr.save # usr name changed, commit the change!
```

When you say that a user is created in the console each time you run `User.create`, are you sure they're actually being created?  In console you'll see a `User` returned each time, but the `id` would be `nil` if there had been errors in the create attempt.  If you run `create!` instead you'd see an exception if the `User` had validation errors (like a duplicate email) and did not save.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The create indeed created multiple records in my table. The change to validate_uniqueness_of function fixed the creation. Should i exit and reopen my rails console every time i make a code change or is it taken care of automatically.

Comment: oh yes, that would have done it.  You need to reload the console when you make code changes, or at least run `load user.rb`, for example, to reload the changed class.  Although things tend to get a little weird when you do that (for example validations would be included each time and run multiple times afterward).

Comment: @user993797 You can just type `reload!` in `rails console` and it will reload (almost) everything.